# как сделать enum с типом decimal в c#

Tags: c#, enum

как сделать enum с типом decimal в c#? просто я хотел разгрузить метод и решил перебросить переменные с типом decimal(у меня их очень много) но оказалось что enum с типом decimal сделать не получается

есть ли какая-то возможность это сделать?

Comment: В чем проблема занести это все в простую коллекцию/массив? `Enum` не является хранилищем данных.

Comment: нет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535046/enum-with-decimal-values-or-some-like-this

Comment: мне нужно занести не просто значения, а именно переменные, чтобы потом их изменять

Comment: Вы не ответили на мой вопрос. Ну вот допустим `var values = new Dictionary<string, int>{ ["value1"] = 5 };`... `values["value1"] = 10; Console.WriteLine(values["value1"]); // 10`, удобный и понятный способ, который и меняется, и хранится в одном месте, чем он вам не угодил-то? `string` и `int` можете поменять на все, что угодно, хоть вложенные делать.

Comment: извините, сразу не понял, спасибо все работает

Comment: перечисление `enum` - это набор констант, а не переменные

Comment: то есть в enum их потом в коде изменять нельзя?

Comment: @Али-МухаммадЗакарьяев конечно же нет.

Comment: все понял, спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сгруппировать константы можно вручную, например с помощью статического класса.

```
public static class MyDecimal
{
    public const decimal Value1 = 3.14m;
    public const decimal Value2 = 256.123m;
}
```

Можно даже сделать объявление почти как в перечислении.

```
public static class MyDecimal
{
    public const decimal
        Value1 = 3.14m,
        Value2 = 256.123m;
}
```

использовать просто

```
Console.WriteLine(MyDecimal.Value1);
```

Comment: а можно чтобы были не константы, чтобы использовать их в другом классе или функции, методе

Comment: @Али-МухаммадЗакарьяев вы разработчик, вам и решать, что это должно быть. Если появился новый вопрос, можете задать его отдельно.